# Dockerized NGINX: host not found in upstream "odoo:8069"

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am learning NGINX Reverse Proxy from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-nginx-letsencrypt-easy-secure-reverse-proxy-40165ba3aee2/

I use dockerized NGINX. My end goal is to host Odoo with HTTPS. Right now, I am learning how to reverse proxy (Odoo use port 8069, e.g. 127.0.0.1:8069 to access Odoo instead of 127.0.0.1)

I understand the concept behind Proxy and Reverse Proxy but I still have not figured out about the technical part such as upstream. I am actually curious why the article require upstream (article related to reverse proxy I seen on on stackoverflow did not use upstream)

**Expected result:**

By visiting example.com, reverse proxy will sending request (by user) coming from example.com to 127.0.0.1:8069

**Actual result:**

NGINX container commit suicide.

`sudo docker-compose up reverse` output

```
Starting reverse ... done
Attaching to reverse
reverse    | 2020/04/22 14:04:05 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "odoo:8069" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/odoo.conf:2
reverse    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "odoo:8069" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/odoo.conf:2
reverse exited with code 1
```

`cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-available/odoo.conf` output

```
upstream odoo {
  server        odoo:8069;
}

server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://odoo;
  }
}
```

---- Update as requested by @user2932688

`cat docker-compose.yml` output

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse:
    container_name: reverse
    hostname: reverse
    image: nginx:1.16.1
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./volumes/nginx/config/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/certs:/etc/ssl/private
  web:
    image: odoo:13.0
    container_name: odoo
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./volumes/odoo/config:/etc/odoo
      - ./volumes/odoo/addons:/mnt/extra-addons
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
  db:
    image: postgres:11.7
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

`sudo docker-compose up` output (running services: reverse, web, db)

Actual result: Reverse container commit suicide.

```
 sudo docker-compose up
Creating network "docker-odoo-https_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "docker-odoo-https_odoo-web-data" with default driver
Creating volume "docker-odoo-https_odoo-db-data" with default driver
Creating reverse                ... done
Creating docker-odoo-https_db_1 ... done
Creating odoo                   ... done
Attaching to reverse, docker-odoo-https_db_1, odoo
```

...
    reverse    | 2020/04/22 15:23:27 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "odoo:8                                                                             069" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/odoo.conf:2
    reverse    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "odoo:8069" in /etc/nginx                                                                             /conf.d/sites-enabled/odoo.conf:2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that to work you need `odoo` container in your docker-compose.yaml, which would listen on port `8069`. Right now it looks like it can't be resolved.

If you have it in your docker-compose - please let us see it so we can help you.

Plus by doing `sudo docker-compose up reverse` you are starting only `reverse` out of whole docker-compose. though you should start `odoo` first. or start everything by `sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` I wrote **reverse** before **web** and **db**, I have added the config in the question.

The result: Reverse container commit suicide, is this in normal scenario a bad practice?

I did confirm revising the services order did not affect the result.

I also did `sudo docker-compose start db web` and then `sudo docker-compose up reverse`. It did not affect the result aswell.

Comment: now i see the problem, it should be `server web:8069;` but not `server        odoo:8069;` `web` is the name it will be available inside of docker-compose network. (i've never used `container_name: odoo`)
also you can use `depends_on: web` inside of `reverse` so docker compose make sure that web is running before starting reverse

Comment: I see. I changed it to `server web:8069` and add `depends_on: web`. The reverse container did not commit suicide.

I tested it by making request to mydomain.com, the reverse proxy did not send the request (by user) coming to 127.0.0.1:8069. Instead, I went to NGINX's welcome page.

Comment: My bad. It's the user's fault. I think Internet Explorer did not support reverse proxy (the reverse proxy sent the request to the nginx server instead of port 8069), while Google Chrome force HTTPS (refused to connect). I use Microsoft Edge and it works.